# MySQL: выдача нулевого значения вместо NULL

Tags: mysql

Как сделать, чтобы запрос вернул 0 в случае если нет связей с другой таблице в результате чего `СOUNT` выдает `NULL`. Так вот как сделать проверку в запросе на выдачу 0, если `COUNT` = `NULL`

```
SELECT
  d.Count AS CountLikes
FROM ... 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 `likes` d
ON
  d.IdNote = a.idArticle AND
  d.LikeType = 2
```

Comment: COALESCE(d.count,0)

Comment: Это вместо d.Count AS CountLikes?

Comment: [да](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Comparison_Operators.html)

Answer (score 4):

Используйте функцию `IFNULL()` [ссылка на w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp):

```
SELECT ProductName,UnitPrice*(UnitsInStock+IFNULL(UnitsOnOrder,0))
FROM Products
```

В вашем же случае это будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT
  IFNULL(d.Count,0) AS CountLikes
FROM ... 
LEFT
  outer JOIN `likes` d
ON
  d.IdNote = a.idArticle AND
  d.LikeType = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

*Ответ из комментариев*: можно воспользоваться функцией `COALESCE()`, которая возвращает первый не NULL-аргумент.

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(d.Count, 0) AS CountLikes
FROM ...
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  `likes` d
ON
  d.IdNote = a.idArticle AND
  d.LikeType = 2
```

Таким образом, если `d.Count` принимает числовое значение - будет возвращено оно, если `NULL`, следующий аргумент, в данном случае - 0.